# Spring security saml2.0 sso with wso2

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Spring SAML2.0 For SSO and Identity server as WSO2 5.4.0
I have done that with the SAML single sign on and now I want to define the role of the USERS and according to the roles of the user they can access the some sort of functionality in my application.

Ideally the User credential is stored in wso2 identity server and I defined there the role of the user.

When I fetch the assertion xml which is coming from wso2 IDP I can't find the role of the users.

Comment: You mean in the assertion comes from the Identity Server, you can't find the role claim?

Comment: Thank u @MadurangaSiriwardena got it

Comment: If you were able to find a solution for your issue please consider the steps as a answer so that if someone else got the same issue it will help them

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena Hi if we want to authorization using saml sso with wso2 idp we need to add the role claims which comes as part of assertion xml. Spring is not itself enabled for authorization we need fetch the user role from assertion xml and assign it against the user.